# Handle dynamically generated form element at controller side in java

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate

I am generating following input text box using a Javascript function. Each text box will have a unique id which will be incremented as well as unique name as follow.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" indexed="true" id="skills_0" name="skills_0">
<input type="text" class="form-control" indexed="true" id="skills_1" name="skills_1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" indexed="true" id="skills_2" name="skills_2">
```

I want to retrieve a value filled by user in this text box at my controller. I am using the Hibernate framework.
Normally in Hibernate I used to retrieved values as follows:

```
String name=request.getParameter("name");
```

But I am confused how to retrieved values of this dynamically generated text box at the controller side.Also how can i know how many skills are added by the user at my controller? i.e is how many textbox are generated by user at run time..

Comment: either generate the inputs with different "name" for each one, or iterate over list of all the parameters in request and check if there are the one you need.

Comment: Yes I have edited my question I can also assign unique name to each dynamically generated textbox...But then the question is how can i know how many times user has generated textbox at server side

Comment: Just iterate over all parameters, and check the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

in Http the `<form>` is send using only name attributes of a input:

`<input name="someName" value="someValueOfsomeNameInput"/>`

so in request it looks usually like `...&someName=someValueOfsomeNameInput` - it is not using "`id`" at all when sending request.

Either generate the inputs with different "name" for each one, or iterate over list of all the parameters in request and check if there are the one you need.

All parameters from input will be send, so in order to get the list you could add some prefix to the name, and check if the parameter starts with this unique prefix, so you can group them together by this prefix. You can also try to have same "name" for each parameter, then maybe they will come together as list. This is a snippet of code that iterate over all parameters in a request, use it to check what parameters do you get in your request and how they are structured.

```
    public void sysoRequestParameters(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {

                Enumeration<String> parameterNames = req.getParameterNames();
                while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
                    System.out.println("--------------------------");
                    System.out.println("parameter name = " + paramName);
                    String[] paramValues = req.getParameterValues(paramName);
                    System.out.println("parameter values:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                        String paramValue = paramValues[i];
                        System.out.println(paramValue);
                    }
                }
                out.close();
            }

   }
```